# How to send SMS through connected mobile from any Windows OS? it should support android,Symbian or any platform mobile

Tags: c#, android, vb.net, sms

I want to send sms using C# or vb.net via connected mobile (nokia,samsung,gsm modem or any similar medium).In windows xp we had AT COMMANDS through which we can send sms from any connected mobile.

Can any one suggest me any solution to send sms using any mobile android based or symbion or from any windows operating system XP,Vista or Windows 7 (vista and windows 7 don't provide hyperterminal facility).

Comment: Question: Are you specifically looking to send through connected handset? Why not just use one fo the many sms api's, accessible from .net?

Comment: Louis van tonder can you give me example of those api.if your are talking about online SMS services then i don't want to use them due to some reason.

Comment: Yeah, I am talking about online services.

Comment: @LouisvanTonder can you suggest me something else,that i can build using C# or .net .Is it possible to send sms from any mobile (android based,symbian or else) using single application.

Comment: If you use the mobile as data connection to the pc, which all mobiles should be able to provide, you can use any internet accessible sms api. Maybe you should elaborate more on what you are trying to do, and why you don't want to take certain approaches?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with com port

open com port and send AT command to send sms

Comment: ,i know that i can do it with com port,will it work same with android too. can you give me code for it.